# how to make banner take up to 75% of the screen using tailwind`

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I've been trying to have my banner show till about 75% of the screen height without getting cropped. I didn't use `h-screen` cause it takes the full height of the screen and `h-96` is too small. How do I get the desired result?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="dark">
  <head>
    <link href="/public/output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Tailwind</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav>
  The Navbar
  </nav>

 <!-- Banner -->
    <div class="bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat h-48 lg:h-96" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/1280x614/?nature');">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set any required value for height (and for width too) using the
template: `h-[value]`

**For example:**

```
h-[75%]
```

**or**

```
h-[100px]
```

Comment: it's getting little cropped at the top and bottom. any way to solve that?

Comment: my pic is 1280x614px in dimensions

Comment: What do you have in your output.css? Are there any margins or paddings for the banner?

Comment: try `h-[75vh]` then